# In Ethereum Name Service, once I won an auction, can I assign any address to that name?

Tags: ens

Once I have won the auction, I can set the address for the name I just won. I use the setAddr function in the ENS Public Resolver Contract.

The question is if that address can be any address or it must be the same address I used to make the auction?

What if in the later future I want to set that name to another address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is if that address can be any address or it must be the same address I used to make the auction?

Yes, there is no requirement that your address be the same as the owner of the name.

In fact, you can have three different addresses:

- The "deed" owner, which can always get control of the name
- The name owner, which is the current administrator
- The address that the name resolves to (where funds are sent to, if people send funds to that name)

See the distinction between deed and name ownership in the [ENS docs](http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#managing-ownership).

> What if in the later future I want to set that name to another address?

As long as you're the owner of the ENS name, you can set the name to resolve to whatever address you want, over and over.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but just one question about that, it means that I can assign that name to any address even if it isn't mine? Because I beleive that during the setAddr process, the private key of the address linked to the name is never asked.

Comment: That's correct, you do not need to have control of the account.